# How to count users daily/monthly/weekly using tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I want to count the number of active users weekly/monthly using tableau and whenever a users opens the app (ios or android) the users should be counted as active.

Answer (score 1):

Your friendly Tableau Server/Online administrator has all the data you need to do this.

When you say "the app" do you mean Tableau Mobile ?  That might be a bit more tricky to do, but if there are certain workbooks that you only publish to mobile devices that would make the job easier.

Comment: Our Tableau admin provided us with a datasource of the user information and we built reports off that.  You can't get the data without access to the postgreSQL tables.